# values not saving in database

Tags: php, mysql

Once we click on Button,  i am trying to update values in Database & along with that i need to download pdf....

once values [**tracking_id**]  are updated in database, than only i can able to download pdf....

When i click on button its not updating **tracking_id** column in database.... instead it showing **0**....

**shippinglabel.php**  [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aGS8f4GC)

```
<?php 
$db_handle2= new DBController();
$star="select pincode , xpressbee from shippment_details where xpressbee='xpressbee' and pincode='$pinc'";
$resultstar = $db_handle2->runSelectQuery($star);

if($resultstar)
    { 
       if($orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]==''){
?>

    <input type="button" name="shipment" id="xpress" value="xpress" 
    onclick="createshipment('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>')" />

<?php }}
?>

<?php 
if($orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]!='' && $orderrecords[$k]["shipping_name"]=='xpress')
{?>

<a target="_blank"
href="/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId=<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>" 
id="pdfdownload" >

<input type="button" name="shipment" value="DOWNLOAD" /></a>
<?php }?>

<Script>

function createshipment(orderid)
    {

      var assignee='<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']?>';
      alert(orderid);
      $.ajax({
        url: "xpressshipment.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'orderid='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,
        success: function(data){
          if(data==1)
          {
            $("#pdfdownload").show();
            $("#ekartc").hide();           
          }
          if(data==2){alert("order id not proper.");}
          if(data==0){alert("First Enter Tracking Id.");}
          window.location ="/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId="+orderid;
          //location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
```

**xpressshipment.php**  [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xNEQFKCw)

```
<?php

$data = 
array (
'OrderNo' => $order_id,
'AirWayBillNO' => $resultc[0]['awb'],
);

$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";
$res=json_decode($curl_response);


if($res->AddManifestDetails[0]->ReturnMessage=='successful')
{
    $sqli="update  do_order set tracking_id='".$resultc[0]['awb']."',shipping_name='xpress' , current_status='99' where order_id='".$order_id."'";
    $resulti=$db_handle->executeUpdate($sqli);

    $sqlj = "update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."',status='assigned' WHERE awb ='".$resultc[0]['awb']."'"; 
    $resultj = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlj);          
}
```

**xpressdownload.php**  [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bgWyc3Xs)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['orderId']) && $_GET['orderId']!='')
{
  $orderid=$_GET['orderId'];

}
else
{
   echo 2;
}

$sqlorder = "SELECT comments,tracking_id,order_id,order_date,address,product_type,alternateno,sku,customer_email,price,customer_name,phone_number,payment_type,product_name from do_order where order_id='".$orderid."' limit 1";
$resultdoorder = $db_handle->runSelectQuerys($sqlorder);
if($resultdoorder['tracking_id']=='')
{
  echo "0";

}
else
{
    // pdf download code
}
```

Comment: if nothing else, the orderid for the data in the ajax call should be order_id

Comment: @GarrGodfrey everyone can't become CEO like you, there is a reason for that.....

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine & saved my rest of the day..... i love to give billion upvotes if you post your answer.......